# Why am I getting segmentation fault here?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, pthreads

I have the following code, where I try to write something into the stack. I write at the bottom of the stack, which the application still hasn't touched (Note that stack grows downwards and **stackaddr** here points to the bottom).

However I get segmentation fault even after doing **mprotect** to give both write and read permissions to that memory region. I get segmentation fault even if I use the compilation flag **-fno-stack-protector**. What is happening here?

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
void * stackaddr;
int * plocal_var;
size_t stacksize;

pthread_getattr_np(pthread_self(), &attr);
pthread_attr_getstack( &attr, &stackaddr, &stacksize );

printf( "stackaddr = %p, stacksize = %d\n", stackaddr, stacksize );

plocal_var = (int*)stackaddr;
mprotect((void*)plocal_var, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
*plocal_var = 4;
printf( "local_var = %d!\n", *plocal_var );
```

Comment: Could you try and come up with a title that at least hints at what your question is about?

Comment: Print the value of `stackaddr` and then look in `/proc/pid/maps` to verify that there is actually memory mapped there. Also, check the return value of `mprotect` -- it will probably give you some clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost certainly trying to `mprotect()` pages which are not yet mapped.  You should check the return code: `mprotect()` is probably returning -1 and setting `errno` to `ENOMEM` (this is documented in the [`mprotect(2)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect)).

Stack pages are mapped on demand, but the kernel is clever enough to distinguish between page faults caused by an access at or above the current stack pointer (which are caused by valid attempts to expand the stack downwards, by decrementing the stack pointer, and then performing a read or write to some positive offset from the new value), and page faults caused by an access below the stack pointer (which are not valid).