# Calling mprotect on the main thread's stack always fails

Tags: c, multithreading, mprotect

I attempt to call `mprotect` on the main thread's stack, but it always fails. Every time I try, it yields an `ENOMEM` error. And I have checked in /proc/[pid]/maps the whole stack is mapped in the address space. However, I can successfully call `mprotect` on a child thread's stack from the main stack. There must be something special about the main thread's stack that prevents itself from being changed by `mprotect`. But I can't find any document for this. Anyone has an idea?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * addr;
size_t size;

void * thread(void * tls) {
    sleep(1);
    if (mprotect(addr, size, PROT_NONE) == -1) perror(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_getattr_np(pthread_self(), &attr);
    pthread_attr_getstack(&attr, &addr, &size);

    pthread_t th;
    pthread_create(&th, NULL, thread, NULL);
    sleep(2);
    pthread_join(th, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when I am trying to execute the above code, am getting output "Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: @Startup That's the error message for `ENOMEM`.

Answer (score 3):

You trying to mprotect the pages which are not mapped. If you check the source of [pthread_attr_getstack](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/pthread__attr__getstack_8c_source.html), you will find that there is no mmap.Stack pages are mapped on demand. [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730468/why-am-i-getting-segmentation-fault-here)

Comment: However, I checked the maps listed in /proc/[pid]/maps. The entire stack [addr, addr + size) is listed as mapped.

Comment: I have posted a new answer because I can provide a big comment. Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this [code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/enable-execute-stack-mprotect.c) to protect meory. It's working fine with your code.
Call the method like this->

```
39     pthread_attr_getstack(&attr, &addr, &size);
40     __enable_execute_stack(&addr);
```

and compile : `gcc your_code.c __enable_execute_stack_code.h -lpthread -fbuilding-libgcc`

Comment: Do you mean `__enable_execute_stack(addr);`, without the `&` in front of `addr`? It doesn't work, still returns `ENOMEM`.

Comment: Using `&addr` protects the memory page that stores `addr`, which is not what I want. I want to protect the stack of the main thread, which is pointed to by `addr`.